# downloading csv files from a feed that have special characters

Tags: python, csv, operating-system

Good afternoon everyone,

I wrote a code that connect to a feed and download several CSV files that I ingest.
Some of the csv files have special characters in their names which the OS prevent me from saving to disk.
any elaborate way of deleting those special characters?

my code snippet:

```py
collectionDownload = 'https://www.myfeedwebsite.com/api/' + collectionID + '/download/csv'
response2 = requests.get(collectionDownload, headers=headers)
if response2.status_code == 200:
    file = open(f"{i['attributes']['name']}.csv", "wb")
    file.write(response2.content)
    file.close()
```

the ['name'] is the name of the CSV which is published by the feed.

I could create a try block which hold all special characters and remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```py
import re

file_name = 'file_გამარჯობა_name'
cleaned_file_name = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.,\s]', '', file_name)
print(cleaned_file_name)
```

Output:

```
file__name
```

This code will remove any characters that are not:

- Alphanumeric (`a-zA-Z0-9`)
- Underscore (`_`)
- Hyphen (`-`)
- Period (`.`)
- Comma (`,`)
- Space (`\s`)

You can modify the pattern inside the square brackets of the regex to include or exclude any specific characters you want to keep or remove.

Comment: nice I'll check it